# 3G creates more network load than GSM or LTE in an Android application, why?

Tags: android, tcp, gsm, 3g, lte

I have developed an Android app and I needed to know the network load created with different cellular technologies (GSM, 3G and LTE).

Surprisingly (at least for me), the comparison of total load network result is LTE < GSM < 3G, when I was expecting GSM < 3G < LTE.

Analyzing the traces it is possible to see that the normal messages from the application have a length of 700-800 bytes. Moreover, in GSM appear some messages with a length of 1400 bytes and, in 3G, the amount of theses big messages is greater, what explains why the final amounts of network load ends like LTE < GSM < 3G, but, in the application code there is nothing related to the networks selection, so the behavior of the app should remain the same independently of the cellular technology employed, which I select from the android OS settings.

Does anyone know what can be these big messages? or why are they originated?

EDIT: The LTE measurements were taken with a Samsung galaxy S III with LTE support, but the 3G and GSM measurements were taken with a Samsung galaxy S III without LTE support, do you think that it can affect to the traffic generated?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "network load"?  Are you analysing protocols within your Android device with a tool similar to Wireshark, or are you analysing everything that comes out of the antenna of the Android device?

Comment: I mean the tcp packets sent in the communication. I use tcpdump in the server side.

Comment: Not sure then.  The air interface network is completely different for each radio access technology, but this is well below the tcp layer.

Comment: I concluded that LTE has better quality of signal and hence less retransmissions (which also explains that the big packets can be due to the retransmission)

Comment: Sounds likely - so the result is only valid for that particular time/place then.

Comment: From my practice, LTE is using much more conversation than other two.